# How do you change the background colour of chart in d3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

How can I change the background colour behind certain regions of a plot in d3.js so I can make something like this? [image: Example]

Comment: I guess you can draw some rects with the desired width and colour as the svg first childs and then create the chart.

Comment: You can use d3.svg.area().

Comment: can you put code on jsfiddle/plunker

Comment: Did it with some rects and it worked fine. Thanks guys.

Comment: In case you still need it. I made an example with area highlight. http://vida.io/documents/TzcZJX4itBebKciQZ